# How to read docx/pdf file from HDFS using pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, hdfs

I want to read DOCX/PDF file from Hadoop file system using pyspark, Currently I am using pandas API. But in pandas we have some limitation we can read only CSV, JSON, XLSX & HDF5. Its not support any other format.
Currently my code is :

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from hdfs import InsecureClient

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Random")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

client_hdfs = InsecureClient('http://192.00.00.30:50070')
with client_hdfs.read('/user/user.name/sample.csv', encoding = 'utf-8') as reader:
  df = pd.read_csv(reader,index_col=0)
  print df
```

I am able to read CSV using above code, any other API's which can solve this problem for DOC/PDF?

Comment: Is your data stored in docx? Generally data should come in csv or json file format.

Comment: yes, In HDFS path I have place one doc file, I want to read or parse same file. require the same for PDF files as well(since all these files are storing binary format)

Comment: @Tony HDFS can contain any file. Those are only two common *human readable formats*. The fact of the matter is there isn't a popular PDF or DOCX Hadoop InputFormat class