# parse docx and pdf in hdfs

Tags: python, parsing, hadoop, hdfs

I want to parse/extract content stored in pdf and docx files which are stored in hdfs. The python libraries available (like docx2txt, pdfminer) are not working in the hdfs. These files are giving a binary output if I try to read with the native hdfs libraries.  Are there any python libraries which can do such task? Or a way in which we can convert the binary files to extract the data.

Comment: Can you please show the code with the binary data? Why aren't you decoding the binary to a String? Or even just copying the file from HDFS to do processing with those libraries which do not know the concept of mapreduce to read partial files?

Comment: For anyone that does answer this, it's a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357302/how-to-read-docx-pdf-file-from-hdfs-using-pyspark

Comment: For decoding the binary to a string I have to first know the schema of the file. In real case scenario, it is not possible to know the schema for each and every file. That is why I need a library for that. There is already a tika library which does such type of task. But it is not able to take hdfs paths.

Comment: I personally don't know about schemas of these files, but I have read few examples that index such files using Apache Solr or Apache Nifi, nothing Python. See https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html and https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/81694/extracttext-nifi-custom-processor-powered-by-apach.html  and https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/163776/parsing-any-document-with-apache-nifi-15-with-apac.html